# Pause button not working on background video

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Im trying to create a nice background video that has some text on top as well as a button that i can use to pause and unpause the video, the video works fine and loops, but i cant pause the video.

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
</head>

<body>
<video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
<source src="dudleyByDrone.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="polina">
    <h1>dudley</h1>
    <p>Directed by joe bloggs
        <p><a href="">original article</a>
          <p>blah blah</p>
            <button>Pause</button>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

js (I got this code from [here](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK) and though it says "// only functional if "loop" is removed" i have tried removing "loop" and it still doesn't pause:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
var pauseButton = document.querySelector("#polina button");

function vidFade() {
    vid.classList.add("stopfade"); 
}

vid.addEventListener('ended', function()
{
// only functional if "loop" is removed 
   vid.pause();
// to capture IE10
   vidFade();
}); 
pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
   vid.classList.toggle("stopfade");
 if (vid.paused) {
   vid.play();
   pauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
} else {
   vid.pause();
   pauseButton.innerHTML = "Paused";
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the button with more specificity.

```
 var playPause = document.querySelector("#playPause");
```

There are changes throughout the source `playButton` changed to `playPause` which is not the problem only a preference. An indirect selector may or may not work well with `document.querySelector()` since it tends to accept simple selectors more readily (from experience, not sure if it's documented.)

#### SNIPPET

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
var playPause = document.querySelector("#playPause");

function vidFade() {
  vid.classList.add("stopfade");
}

vid.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  // only functional if "loop" is removed 
  vid.pause();
  // to capture IE10
  vidFade();
});
playPause.addEventListener("click", function() {

  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play();
    playPause.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    playPause.innerHTML = "Paused";
  }
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
</head>

<body>
  <video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div id="polina">
    <h1>dudley</h1>
    <p>Directed by joe bloggs
      <p><a href="">original article</a>
        <p>blah blah</p>
        <button id="playPause">Play/Pause</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Worked after i put a semi colon at the end of the your java script snippet.

Comment: Indeed sir, it is a copy of your JavaScript, I just changed the variable. With or without semi-colons it works, but it is a good habit to use them as you have pointed out. Happy coding. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The following code should allow you to pause the video

```
$(function() {
    $('#polina button').on("click", function() {
        $('video')[0].pause();
    });
});
```

EDIT: changing `pause();` to `play();` will do exactly what you think it will.

Comment: I've added jQuery script type in the head of my html, and have replaced all my js with this: $(document).ready(function() {
 '   
    $('.textOverlay button').on("click", function() {
        alert("test");
        $('video')[0].pause();
    });
}); '

Comment: ...right. That doesn't tell me if it works/doesn't work.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Sorry it's not letting me post code in a more presentable way.